# How to fill HTML form fields from SQL server with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to get data and dump them to my HTML form from the SQL server. For example I type a name to my HTML form and I want to dump all the information of that name from the database ( last name, email etc.).

I created the form and a simple PHP connector that finds the name and the other information for that name ( last name). I can echo it on PHP file but I want to show it on the input last name as a value so I can use it for JavaScript purpose.

```
<form class="form-inline">

  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
      <tr>


        <td><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label> </td>
        <td><input type="name" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="last name"></td>
        <td><label for="firstname">First Name:</label> </td>
        <td><input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="first name"></td>


      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it as the *value* for the HTML input.

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $row->last_name; ?>">
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I got this to work

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="' . $row["POLCustName"] . '">
```

There was a `<?php` to start and an `echo` to do the Form within the PHP.  But for the value of the SQL row to process, you needed the quotes and then a single quote to allow the PHP to work, otherwise you just got the statement above.  Also, it required the period before and after as shown. Anyway, this worked for me.